# AWS Lambda Language Versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have been trying to determine whether my version of Python is supported by AWS Lambda. There doesn't appear to be any easy to find documentation on this (there are articles about which versions are EOLed, and tutorials that recommend a particular version, but not indication about whether this is up to date).

The alternative is to deploy and see if it works, which may cause errors that do not manifest straight away.

Is there any maintained list of which versions of which languages are supported by AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The versions are listed in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html):

[image]